# How does Dozer Java API perform?

Tags: java, dozer

I have two questions related to the performance of Dozer using its Java API:

1. In general, is mapping faster than using Dozer XML configuration? or are they about the same?
2. How does it compare with other Java mapping frameworks, such as Orika?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general mapping performance is the same either using XML configuration or Java API.

Performance will depends on your application (use cases), basically Orika perform better than Dozer or other mapping (reflection based frameworks), because it use bytecode generation behind the scenes.

IMO when you have to render HTML and access to a remote data store, the mapper performance may be untidy.

Here is some benchmarks  http://bit.ly/pJ7n6t

Answer (score 2):

I just stumbled upon GeDA - a really fast bean mapping framework according to http://inspire-software.com/confluence/display/GeDA/Benchmarks , and with Spring integration support.

Had 2 classes with 4 simple fields - String, String, Date, boolean. 1000000 conversions of such object took 100ms with GeDA and 1000ms with Orika.

Knowing that Orika is 10 times faster comparing to Dozer, you can imagine how GeDA vs. Dozer performs

Comment: Added Dozer to this performance test, it takes 4000ms for Dozier. In total = GeDA is 40 times faster than Dozer in this simple test